# Why does gridview expand like it has the data, but doesn't display the data?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

The data is coming through fine, and I can successfully display the data the in a list box, but when i try to do this in a grid view or list view, i get these results. I feel like something small is missing here.

I've set the two way, and update property source on the textboxes, but still no visible data shown. I know it has the data, because it expands like [I captured in this screenshot](https://gyazo.com/605d734e2688d15c7ae2c130452b4515).

LeadingCauseOfDeath Class

```
public class LeadingCausesOfDeath : BasePropertyHandler
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string _113_cause_name { get;set;}
    public string Cause_name { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int Deaths { get; set; }
    public int AgeAdjustedDeathRate { get; set; }

}
```

**XAML View**

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource HomePageVM}}">
    <StackPanel >
        <NavigationView PaneDisplayMode="Top" IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" >
            <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="Family"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="History"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="About"/>
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        </NavigationView>

        <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Data, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
              IsSwipeEnabled="true"
              SelectionMode="Single"
                  BorderThickness="10" BorderBrush="Blue">

            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="4" Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>

            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Cause_name}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Year}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Deaths}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding State}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>

        </GridView>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**View model**

```
 private ObservableCollection<LeadingCausesOfDeath> _data;

    public ObservableCollection<LeadingCausesOfDeath> Data
    {
        get
        {
            return _data;
        }
        set
        {
            _data = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Data");
        }
    }
    public HomePageVM()
    {
        GetData();
    }

    private async void GetData()
    {
        var service = new ServiceForApi();
        Data = new ObservableCollection<LeadingCausesOfDeath>();
        Data = await service.GetFDAStuff();
        OnPropertyChanged("Data");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged( string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code of `LeadingCausesOfDeath` class as well?

Comment: Done @MartinZikmund

Comment: I don't have an answer, but you're making a few unnecessary calls.  First, you have an OnPropertyChanged call in the setter of `Data` and in the `GetData` method.  You only need the setter one.  Next, you're initializing the `ObservableCollection` with a new empty collection in `GetData`, then you're redefining it again in the next line where you call `GetFDAStuff`.  Now, this may not be the cause of your binding problems, but I don't know what your `GetFDAStuff` method looks like.

Comment: Also, you mention you are updating your textboxes, but they will only update if you replace the entire `LeadingCausesOfDeath` model... not if you change the properties within the model.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers on the property change calls. I was a tad over zealous on that. 
The data result is there, and the UI sees that it's there, but the gridview will not display the content.
I can display all of this data if I bind to a list box, but as soon as I use the gridview or listview, it will not display it. @LeeMcPherson

Comment: Again, not sure if this will solve your problem, but there is no need to use "TwoWay" binding for a GridView's ItemSource.  Think of the TwoWay as being necessary only if the UI control will change your data, like a TextBox will if you write into it.  The property fields might get changed by your datatemplate UI controls, but the ObservableCollection won't get changed by the GridView.  Also, the default UpdateSourceTrigger is PropertyChanged so you don't need that either.

Comment: Finally, putting a GridView inside a StackPanel is a bad idea.  StackPanel will expand as much as it needs to fit the entire content.  So, the automatic virtualization that GridView does is lost because it stretches to fit all the items.  Use a Grid with two RowDefinitions... first set to Auto, second set to *

Comment: ^^ Actually this is my best guess as to why it's not showing...

Comment: Hey, you got it! If possible put that as an answer, and i'll accept it. Thank you! @LeeMcPherson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting a `GridView` inside a `StackPanel` is a bad idea. `StackPanel` will expand as much as it needs to fit the entire content. So, the automatic virtualization that `GridView` does is lost because it stretches to fit all the items.

With your `ItemsWrapGrid`'s Orientation set to Vertical, it's probably not expanding at all... it expects a fixed height to fill with items and will expand in the horizontal direction.

Use a Grid with two RowDefinitions... first set to Auto, second set to *

Comment: Off topic, and maybe not allowed but It's a issue I've yet to fully tackle so i'm going to ask.
Do you suppose the issue in this question is virtualization as well? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54653334/is-there-any-known-reasons-my-guis-controls-change-after-changing-to-target-vers